# Installing libraries and enviroment

Tags: python, libraries, openai-api, langchain

I am trying to install these libraries and import these things but I keep getting errors even when I use command prompt to try and install them, any answers?

```
import os
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
from pypdf import PdfReader

# Set OpenAI API Key
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "my API key"

# Initialize classes and directories
persist_directory="chromaPersistance"
embedding = OpenAIEmbeddings()
```

Comment: Have you tried using `pip` to install your packages? Ie: `pip install pypdf` works for me, not sure about langchain but I imagine it is similar.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete error report . You can surround the report with 3` before and 3` after to properly format the output.

Comment: Echoing what @itprorh66 said, please update your question to include your error but without any additional info, I'm thinking you might not have pip added to your path which is why you are unable to install from the command prompt.